# C# interface question

Tags: c#, .net, performance, interface, ienumerable

Is there a cost in passing an object to a function that implements a particular interface where the function only accepts that interface? Like:

```
Change (IEnumerable<T> collection)
```

and I pass:

```
List<T>
LinkedList<T>
CustomCollection<T>
```

which all of them implements IEnumerable. But when you pass any of those to the Change method, are they cast to IEnumerable, thus there is a cast cost but also the issue of losing their unique methods, etc?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there is no cast involved since `List<T>` `IS-A` `IEnumerable<T>`.  This is using polymorphism which does not require casting.

Edit: Here is an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        foo(new List<int>());
    }

    static void foo(IEnumerable<int> list) { }
}
```

The IL for `Main` is:

```
.method private hidebysig static void Main() cil managed
{
    .entrypoint
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: nop 
    L_0001: newobj instance void [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<int32>::.ctor()
    L_0006: call void Program::foo(class [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<int32>)
    L_000b: nop 
    L_000c: ret 
}
```

And as you can see there is no casting involved.  The instance of `List<T>` is pushed onto the stack and them `foo` is called immediately after.

Comment: Plus the object's don't "lose" their methods, they are just not available inside the function.  This is ok because the method only expect IEnumerable<T> and should thus only use the methods available via that interface.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a cost. Since the types already implement IEnumerable, the object should be able to be used straight away (note that this is mostly a guess; I have no idea about how the CLR's vtables really work behind the scenes).

If there is a cost, it will be so amazingly small that, if it makes a difference, you probably shouldn't be using the CLR to begin with.